# Intercepting object changes with Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I need a way to intercept any property was changed in an object mapped with [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/).
I don't want to make subscription to each property, I need one place to give me this info.

How would I go about implementing this?

Comment: If you do `ko.computed(function(){return ko.toJS(self);}).subscribe(function(){ console.log("I will be any time any observable on the 'self' object changes");});` you should be alerted any time any observable changes on the `self` object changes. You won't, however, know which property changed; to know that you'd have to do a lot more work.

Comment: Actually to know which property was changed is needed.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a Dirty Flag, check it out at http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html